# Error 400 to access Instagram API using php

Tags: php, ios, instagram

I'm using Instagram's PHP API which is linked to an iOS application.
The application just likes photos.

My application has been disabled and the message when anyone likes others photos is: 400 api error client limit reached.

I tried to change the app on Instagram and change the path on my server but I get the same error.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Maybe you reached the client limit as the error says? :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a 30 liking limit per hour per Access Token, but this doesn't appear to be the case in our testing.

It would be ideal for Instagram to just define the exact rules in their documentation, then everyone could play within the rules. Instead these threads keep popping up every other day.